# How can I add some resources to android framework?

Tags: android, frameworks, resources

I want to add some resources to android 5.0 framework,and I added some drawable/anim/layout files to /framework/base/core/res/res,and add "" in the public.xml in values directory，then I use "mm" at "/frameworks/base/core/res" to make a framework-res.apk ,and "adb put framework-res.apk /system/framework" ,but it does not work ,system  crashes!

How can I add some resources to framework and it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just add your resources under **/framework/base/core/res/res/Resource_Type_Folder/**.
Make an entry of your resource in public.xml under **/framework/base/core/res/res/values/public.xml**

That's it.
Build your image and you can access it from any app using following syntax:

```
@android:resoure_type/resource_name
```

BR,
Rahul